# Set tableview properties when rotating

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rotation, tableview

I would like to set my `tableview` properties, such as `Height` when rotating the device.
When the device is on portrait mode, I need to set the height property to 320. But if the device is rotated to `landscape` mode, I need to set to a lower value.
I dont know how to do that, if I need to create a property `IBOutlet` or if I need to create an identifier to the tableview.

The app is set to work with `iOS6` and specifically iphone.
Any help I really appreciate.

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UIViewController (UITableViewController) to handle this for you. It is made to do that for free. Don't try to layout your tableView manually. Simply create an instance of UITableViewController and init it with

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
```

If you are not familiar with (model-)View-Controller design pattern I recommend to read how apple has implemented it.
Here is the link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

Well you don't have to resize it manually if you have a UITableViewController, iOS does that for you.
If you do not use Autolayout than you can set the resizing properties like this:

```
[tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```